# How to web-scrape with Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to extract information from a website to Excel. I tried different codes.

I receive

> Run time error 91

```vb
Sub oslobors()
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim nettside As String

    nettside = "www.oslobors.no"

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  
    nettside.Visible = True
    IE.navigate ("www.oslobors.no")


    Do While IE.busy
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Range("A2").Value = nettside
    Range("B2").Value = getElementsByTagName("Handelssymbol").InnerText

    IE.Quit
    Set .IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: where do you get the error message?

Comment: `nettside.Visible = True`this should be `IE.Visible = True`

Comment: and `Set .IE = Nothing` cannot work without a `With` block. Change it to `Set IE = Nothing` • Furthermore `IE.navigate ("www.oslobors.no")` should be `IE.navigate nettside `

Comment: After doing the recommendations of MG92 & PEH, use F8 key to debug your code. It is a step-by-step run of your code.

Comment: Many thanks, this is very much appreciated. I changed the code accordingly, and the run time error 91 was eliminated. However, it was replaced by a compile error message: " sub or function not defined". Trying to work this out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I prefere use the WinHttpRequest object for this:

- Exemple for a post request :

```
Public Function appelPortailPost(strUrl As String, JSONString As String)

On Error GoTo errorHandler

    strUrl = urlPortail & strUrl
    
    Dim objHTTP As New WinHttpRequest
    Dim strResponse As String
      
    
    objHTTP.Open "POST", strUrl, False
    objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    
   
    
    objHTTP.Send JSONString
    strResponse = objHTTP.ResponseText
    Debug.Print strResponse
      If InStr(strResponse, "Cannot") > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Problème dans l'appel Get vers le Portail: " & strUrl
        End
    End If
    
    appelPortailPost = strResponse
    Exit Function
errorHandler:
     'indique le numéro et la description de l'erreur survenue
    Call MsgBox(Err.Number & vbLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Pb de connexion au portail")
    End
End Function
```

- Example for a get request:

```
Public Function appelPortailGet(strUrl As String) As String

    Dim objRequest As Object
    Dim blnAsync As Boolean
    Dim strResponse As String

    Set objRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    strUrl = urlPortail & strUrl
    blnAsync = True
    With objRequest
        .Open "GET", strUrl, blnAsync
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .Send
        While objRequest.ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend
        strResponse = .ResponseText
    End With

    Debug.Print strResponse

    If InStr(strResponse, "Cannot") > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Problème dans l'appel Get vers le Portail: " & strUrl
        End
    End If
    
    appelPortailGet = strResponse
    Exit Function
errorHandler:
    Call MsgBox(Err.Number & vbLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Pb de connexion au portail")
    End

End Function
```

Comment: Many thanks! Much appreciated. As the run time error 91 message has been replaced by a compile error message ("sub or function not defined"), I will probably try a code using the WinHttpRequest object. Thanks again.